# Multiple view for multiple devices in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

What can be the best way for architecting an ASP .Net MVC project, which have common web service part and multiple views for multiple devices. I have started with a JQuery mobile project, and have view for mobile devices. Now I need to add web api controllers that should work as web services. Also another View part is needed for desktop browsers.

Is it good to assign different Areas to group different Views?

Web Request Flow:

1. Route mobile client request to MVCController in Mobile Area, and desktop client request to MVCController in Desktop Area from RouteConfig
2. Call web api controller(common) from MVC controllers
3. Return corresponding View from MVC controller

Is there any better approach available to do the same? I am confused if webservices and multiple views in same project will increase the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to pursue a responsive design. Ideally you'd end up with just one view for multiple devices instead of multiple views for showing the same information.

Take a look at this [explanation](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/responsive-design-using-foundation-with-asp.net-mvc/).

Comment: Thanks Major Byte.. But I would like to keep using JQuery mobile for mobile client...

Comment: I just gave that link as an explanation, nothing more. Did you even look up if responsive design could be possible with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/)?

Comment: Responsive Web design is possible in Jquery Mob too.. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/grids/rwd-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap framework to achieve a responsive design that will play nicely on any device.

See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

For the most parts, you wont need jQuery mobile.